# Antiderivative for a function for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have:

$$f(x)=\cos(x) \times e^{\sin(x)}$$

and the fitting Antiderivative:

$$F(x)=e^{\sin(x)}$$

Can someone please explain to me how I get from $f(x)$ to $F(x)$? In small steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the substitution rule ? If not, you can "guess" the antiderivate by considering $(e^{sin(x)})'=cos(x)e^{sin(x)}$ (chain rule).

Comment: In general : The antiderivate of $g'(x)\cdot f(g(x))$ simply is $F(g(x))$, where $F(x)$ is the antiderivate of $f(x)$.

Comment: $\int { \cos  (x)\times e^{ \sin  (x) } } dx=\int { { e }^{ \sin { x }  } } d\left( \sin { x }  \right) ={ e }^{ \sin { x }  }+C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just, substitute $u=\sin(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\cos(x)\space\text{d}x$ and use that the integral of $e^x$ equals $e^x$ plus a integration constant.

$$f(x)=\cos(x)e^{\sin(x)}\to\text{F}(x)=\int\cos(x)e^{\sin(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int e^{u}\space\text{d}u=e^u+\text{C}=e^{\sin(x)}+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=sin(x)$, then $dy=cos(x)dx$ , $$ \int e^y dy = e^y =e^{(sin (x))}$$

Comment: I'd be tempted to add "plus C" even though the OP did not ask.